# simple linear regression prediction

Tags: regression, time-series, linear

I am just new at `R` and I am trying to predict food prices. When I run

```
fit1<- lm(buptemp$price~buptemp$year)
predict(fit1, interval = "predict")
```

I get results of my training dataset. I have tried predicting from a different dataset and I get the same result. How do I test using a different dataset with similar objects and how do I predict like 2 months from now?

```
fit1<- lm(buptemp$price~buptemp$year)
predict(fit1, interval = "predict") 
predict(fit1, temp, interval="predict")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can test on other datasets by simply:

```
pred <- predict(fit1,testX)
```

where test is your new data.

```
# You can save your variable by: 
saveRDS(fit1, "fit.rds")

# And later reload it: 
fit1 <- readRDS("fit.rds")
```

and can use after two months.

Comment: thanks..but why is it that i get the same result for the train and testing dataset?

Comment: in reality it shouldn't. Might be the case your data may be quite correlated.Can you tell your line by which you are predicting the test dataset.

Comment: i do not get the question? if you could rephrase it maybe.

Comment: tell me the name of your variable in which test dataset is? and line(code) by which you are predicting its output.

Comment: variable name is test and the line code is predict(buplm, newdata=data.frame(test$year))
   pred <- predict(buplm,test)       tried the two line codes and both give me the same result

Comment: you have only one column 'year' in dataset.

Comment: is it possible for me to use a test data of different length from the training data?

Comment: by length if you mean no. of rows then yes. but number of columns (features) then no.

Comment: yes only one column...so i am predicting the prices for the years

Comment: using the  pred <- predict(buplm,test) how can i include the interval of prediction e.g i want to predict 2months ahead

Comment: try to make  a dataframe of a single value containing  [ 2016 + 2/12 ] if your last value was 2016 in train dataset, and then simply predict for this.

Comment: Technically, you are not saving a variable, but the value stored in that variable, which is an R model object.